# Auth User model in admin page

Tags: python, django

I start add user user authentication to django web site. And add class People with ‍‍‍`User` field by `OneToOneField`. I go to `http: //localhost:8000/admin` page and try to add Student,

but student have only `Born, Record book, User(which have only Имя пользователя, Пароль)`. but don't have `email, first_name, lastname`. Why?

models.py:

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    born = models.DateField() # born date

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(People): # Ingeritance
    record_book = models.CharField(max_length=75) # students record book
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Student:" + self.user.name + ' ' + self.user.surname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/student/%i/" % self.id
```

I see this [rus django book](http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/auth/default.html#user-objects) and this [tango with django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html)

admin.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Professor, Student, Subject, Group, PageLaboratoryWork, MadeLaboratoryWork, LabComment

admin.site.register(Professor)
admin.site.register(Student)
admin.site.register(Subject)
admin.site.register(Group)
admin.site.register(PageLaboratoryWork)
admin.site.register(MadeLaboratoryWork)
admin.site.register(LabComment)
```

Comment: how you check this? you can access to `email,first_name,...` by `user.email`, `user.first_name` of `Student` model.

Comment: i can't filled this filed from admin page

Comment: give your `admin.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from models import Student
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(Student)

admin.site.unregister(User)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

change `admin.py` like this:

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User
    extra = 1

class PeopleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserInline]

admin.site.register(People, PeopleAdmin)
```

Comment: Then ./manage runserver


ERRORS:
<class 'lab.admin.UserInline'>: (admin.E202) 'auth.User' has no ForeignKey to 'lab.Student'.

Comment: @Denis check my edit. use this for `People` model. maybe help you. `AdminInline` dont work for inherited model.

Comment: File "/home/denis/WebDir/laboratory1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 81, in register
    'cannot be registered with admin.' % model.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The model People is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin.

Comment: you can create a specific view for this case. maybe it is best select. or change your mdoel structure.

Comment: i found solution. You directed me, Thanks!